# Transition from damping to runaway in non-Markovian friction

Tags: friction, complex-systems

I am studying the dynamics of a particle with history-dependent friction. That is, the particle velocity $v(t)$ is governed by
$$
\frac{d v}{dt} = -\int_0^t M(s)\, v(t-s) \,ds ,
$$
where $M$ is the memory kernel. For some simple memory models, an analytic solution can be found. In the case where $M(t) = \gamma \delta(t)$ (the Markovian limit), the above reduces to $\frac{dv}{dt}=-\gamma v(t)$, and $\gamma$ is the usual "coefficient of friction." Another analytically solvable model is exponential memory,
$$
M(t) = \frac{\gamma}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau},
$$
where $\tau$ is the memory time ($M(t)\to\gamma\delta(t)$ as $\tau\to 0$). Via Laplace transform, one finds that 
$$
v(t) = v(0) e^{-t/2\tau}\left[ \cos\left(\sqrt{4\gamma\tau-1}  \frac{t}{2\tau}\right) + \frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{4\gamma\tau-1}  \frac{t}{2\tau}\right)}{\sqrt{4\gamma\tau-1}}\right].
$$
A striking feature of this solution is an emergent relationship between the friction coefficient $\gamma$ and the memory time $\tau$. When $\gamma\tau<1/4$, the particle's velocity *diverges* as $t\to\infty$. I'd like to better understand the physics of this transition.

My present interpretation is that the memory time $\tau$ is a measure of velocity "accumulation," while the friction coefficient $\gamma$ is a measure of velocity "decay." In the competition between these two processes, $4$ happens to be the critical number that dictates which one wins out. I'd like to know:

- **Is this competition between growth and decay typical of history-dependent dynamics?** I have a hunch that this is just a special case, based on the fact that both the memory kernel and the underlying Markovian solution are exponential. But I would like something more definitive than a hunch.
- **Are "history-dominated" systems realizable?** The "friction-dominated" regime of this toy model is easy to imagine; it's a damped oscillator that wiggles a bit different from normal. Is there a similarly simple picture for the divergent parameter regime?

Comment: $\gamma\tau\lt 1/4$ means $\sqrt{4\gamma\tau-1}$ becomes imaginary. Doesn't that mean the equation becomes non-physical?

Comment: The $\sin$ and $\cos$ become $\sinh$ and  $\cosh$, so the result is still real.